# Can 2 foreign keys be in one table referencing the same column in another?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, foreign-keys, relational-database

Can 2 foreign keys be in one table referencing the same column in another within relation model?

Comment: "I want your opinions" is an explicit close reason on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.

Comment: Ask 1 clear concise specific researched non-duplicate question per post. PS Your title is a(n easily found) faq (obviously). Please don't ask questions already answered. Before considering posting please read the manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is perfectly fine to have two columns in the `match` table that reference the `teams` table. It means: each match involves two teams, and each of these teams must be present in the `teams` table.

Here is some simplified SQL code:

```
create table team (
    team_id   int primary key,
    team_name varchar(50)
);

create table match (
    match_id       int primary_key,
    home_team_id   int references team(team_id), 
    away_team_id   int references team(team_id),
    date_of_match  date
);
```

Comment: This is an opinion and probably should be a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: @nicomp: OP asked if it is possible to have such set-up: *Is this possible? I think yes, but I want to make sure*. In my view, the question containing the word *opinion* does not automatically qualifies it for closing as opinion-based...